# How to build this date and store it as a string?

Tags: php

I need to build for example:

```
2015-07-01T00:00:00.000-00:00
```

and store it as a string.

---

**I tried with**

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$api_date = '2015-07-01T00:00:00.000-00:00';
$php_date = $today->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s.uP");
echo $api_date;
echo $php_date;
```

**but I got**

```
2015-07-01T00:00:00.000-00:00 // Target
2017-11-28T12:54:34.000000+00:00 // Result
```

Comment: PHP 5.0.0 was end-of-lifed twelve years ago. What version are you *actually* using?

Comment: (as for how to do it, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: But what about the `00:00:00.000-00:00` after the `2015-07-01T`? I don't know what is that.

Comment: Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, and GMT offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I'm not sure that I understood you in the correct way, but in case if .000 means milliseconds and -00:00 means difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours, than that's an answer:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
var_dump($date->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s.vP"));
```

Output: string(29) "2017-11-27T08:37:56.449+00:00"

As far as v option was added just in PHP7 you may use the following code in earlier versions:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$milliseconds = substr(round($date->format('u'), -3), 0, 3);
var_dump($date->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s.").$milliseconds.$date->format('P'));
```

Comment: My output is `string(27) "2017-11-28T12:38:40.v+00:00"`, why is the `v`?

Comment: @emi, I suppose it's because v added in PHP 7.0.0. Which version of php so you use?

Comment: Is **5.6.30**, but if I try `$date->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s.uP");` I got `string(32) "2017-11-28T12:49:29.000000+00:00"` How to get `000` instead of `000000` milliseconds ?

Comment: Now I got `2017-11-28T01:23:36.0+00:00` I give up, I will try to concatenate the `T00:00:00.000-00:00` Thanks anyway.